# RHEL 6.5 RPM Dependencies - Why am I getting an error about a dependency on an RPM that is already installed?

Tags: linux, rpm

I'm trying to upgrade from nscd-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64 to nscd-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 because of a bug. There are several dependencies on glibc RPMs.

Here are the glibc packages that are already installed:

```
[tim@host]~/nscd% rpm -qa | grep glibc
glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
glibc-utils-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
```

Here are the RPMs that I'm trying to use to upgrade:

```
[tim@host]~/nscd% ll
total 35212
-rw-r----- 1 tim appeng   145372 Jan 16 21:04 gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r----- 1 tim appeng  3993348 Jan 16 19:29 glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim appeng 14871492 Jan 17 01:14 glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.i686.rpm
-rw-r----- 1 tim appeng 14883600 Jan 16 19:31 glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r----- 1 tim appeng  1006616 Jan 16 21:50 glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r----- 1 tim appeng   626024 Jan 16 21:48 glibc-headers-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r----- 1 tim appeng   170396 Jan 16 19:56 glibc-utils-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r----- 1 tim appeng    51912 Jan 16 21:13 libXpm-3.5.10-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r----- 1 tim appeng   228352 Jan 16 19:57 nscd-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm
```

Here is the attempted upgrade using rpm:

```
[tim@host]~/nscd% sudo rpm -Uvh *.rpm
[sudo] password for tim:
warning: gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID fd431d51: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        libcap.so.2 is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.i686
        glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6 is needed by (installed) glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
```

A better view of what's happening is afforded by yum:

```
[tim@host]~/nscd% sudo yum localinstall *.rpm
[sudo] password for tim:
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Local Package Process
Examining gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64.rpm: gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64
gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64.rpm: does not update installed package.
Examining glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm: glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64
Marking glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm as an update to glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
Marking glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm as an update to glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
Examining glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.i686.rpm: glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.i686
Marking glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.i686.rpm as an update to glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
Examining glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm: glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64
Marking glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm as an update to glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
Examining glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm: glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64
Marking glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining glibc-headers-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm: glibc-headers-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64
Marking glibc-headers-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining glibc-utils-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm: glibc-utils-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64
Marking glibc-utils-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm as an update to glibc-utils-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
Examining libXpm-3.5.10-2.el6.x86_64.rpm: libXpm-3.5.10-2.el6.x86_64
libXpm-3.5.10-2.el6.x86_64.rpm: does not update installed package.
Examining nscd-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm: nscd-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64
Marking nscd-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm as an update to nscd-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be updated
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.12-1.149.el6_6.4 will be an update
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6 for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.12-1.149.el6_6.4 will be an update
---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.12-1.149.el6_6.4 will be installed
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.12-1.149.el6_6.4 will be installed
---> Package glibc-utils.x86_64 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be updated
---> Package glibc-utils.x86_64 0:2.12-1.149.el6_6.4 will be an update
---> Package nscd.x86_64 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be updated
---> Package nscd.x86_64 0:2.12-1.149.el6_6.4 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201311111358.x86_64/6.5)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6
           Removing: glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201311111358.x86_64/6.5)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6
           Updated By: glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64 (/glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.149.el6_6.4
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

So what I'm getting out of this is that it won't upgrade nscd because there is a failed dependency on "glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6" which is already installed. Can somebody please explain why I'm getting this message and what it actually means?

Also, if there is a better way of doing this without using RHN subscription or Satellite (no connectivity between this environment and the internet due to security).

## ===========================================

Update:
I took Ethan's advice and added the i686 glibc package.

Updated file list:

```
[tim@host]~/nscd% ll
total 38068
-rw-r----- 1 tim appeng   145372 Jan 16 21:04 gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim appeng  4553672 Jan 20 21:42 glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.i686.rpm
-rw-r----- 1 tim appeng  3993348 Jan 16 19:29 glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim appeng 14871492 Jan 17 01:14 glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.i686.rpm
-rw-r----- 1 tim appeng 14883600 Jan 16 19:31 glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r----- 1 tim appeng   170396 Jan 16 19:56 glibc-utils-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r----- 1 tim appeng    51912 Jan 16 21:13 libXpm-3.5.10-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r----- 1 tim appeng   228352 Jan 16 19:57 nscd-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm
```

If I try using rpm to update, it doesn't work. How would I determine what package I need to download which contains libcap.so.2?

```
[tim@host]~/nscd% sudo rpm -Uvh *.rpm
[sudo] password for tim:
warning: gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID fd431d51: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        libcap.so.2 is needed by glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.i686
```

Strangely enough, if I use yum it does work. Why does this work but rpm does not?

```
[tim@host]~/nscd% sudo yum localinstall *.rpm
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Local Package Process
Examining gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64.rpm: gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64
gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64.rpm: does not update installed package.
Examining glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.i686.rpm: glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.i686
Marking glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.i686.rpm as an update to glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
rhel6                                                                                     | 3.9 kB     00:00
rhel6-alt                                                                                 | 3.9 kB     00:00
Marking glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.i686.rpm as an update to glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
Examining glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm: glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64
Marking glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm as an update to glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
Marking glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm as an update to glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
Examining glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.i686.rpm: glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.i686
Marking glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.i686.rpm as an update to glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
Examining glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm: glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64
Marking glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm as an update to glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
Examining glibc-utils-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm: glibc-utils-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64
Marking glibc-utils-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm as an update to glibc-utils-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
Examining libXpm-3.5.10-2.el6.x86_64.rpm: libXpm-3.5.10-2.el6.x86_64
libXpm-3.5.10-2.el6.x86_64.rpm: does not update installed package.
Examining nscd-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm: nscd-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64
Marking nscd-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64.rpm as an update to nscd-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be updated
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be updated
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.149.el6_6.4 will be an update
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.12-1.149.el6_6.4 will be an update
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be updated
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.12-1.149.el6_6.4 will be an update
---> Package glibc-utils.x86_64 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be updated
---> Package glibc-utils.x86_64 0:2.12-1.149.el6_6.4 will be an update
---> Package nscd.x86_64 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be updated
---> Package nscd.x86_64 0:2.12-1.149.el6_6.4 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=================================================================================================================
 Package            Arch         Version                     Repository                                     Size
=================================================================================================================
Updating:
 glibc              i686         2.12-1.149.el6_6.4          /glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.i686                 13 M
 glibc              x86_64       2.12-1.149.el6_6.4          /glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64               12 M
 glibc-common       x86_64       2.12-1.149.el6_6.4          /glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64       107 M
 glibc-utils        x86_64       2.12-1.149.el6_6.4          /glibc-utils-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64         45 k
 nscd               x86_64       2.12-1.149.el6_6.4          /nscd-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64               176 k

Transaction Summary
=================================================================================================================
Upgrade       5 Package(s)

Total size: 133 M
Is this ok [y/N]: n
Exiting on user Command
```

Comment: have you tried ... with rpm file `nscd-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64`

Comment: You missed the `i686` `glibc` update package in your set. You are trying to update one-half of the multilib `glibc` package.

Comment: @MiyaG yes the nscd-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 package is already in the nscd directory in which I'm running the "rpm -Uvh *.rpm" command.

Comment: @EtanReisner can you take a look at the results of adding the i686 glibc package? I updated the body of my question with the results.

Comment: yum probably has more repositories configured than rpm on your system.

Comment: rpm doesn't use "repositories" and libcap isn't in the yum output at all so I don't think that's it. I'm not sure what's going on yet. I did notice that that `gd` package is being ignored as "not an update" though.

Comment: I'm going to guess, but it is just a guess, that the order of the package upgrades via rpm is causing the removal of the current glibc to be attempted before the installation of the new glibc which is causing libcap to be listed for removal (as it depends on libc) which then causes the dependency error for glibc itself in the upgrade... or something like that. Manually sorting the packages as given to `rpm` might help. (`libXpm` is also being ignored as "not an update" for the record).

Answer (score 1):

You could not perform update with rpm, because on install path was glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.i686 package. Only one glibc-common package is allowed.
Look at your yum output. Yum only updates x86_64 rpm. And of course glibc.i686 was not present.